# Javascript + Rails View rendering confusion

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, firebase

I'm using firebase for chat in one of my rails view and I'm not properly able to capture the value of user input to display on the page. This happened when I added the jquery [plugin pageslide.](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/) I must have missed something in my implementation for these two to be working together.

Here the show page for my rails view-

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>

<div id='chat-window'> 
  <%= render 'chat_window' %>
</div>
<a href="#chatty" class="second">Open Chat</a>
```

Here is the chat_window partial-

```
<% if @list.chat_enabled %>
  <%= render 'chat' %>
<% else %>
  <% if @list.owner?(current_user) %>
    <%= link_to 'Get ' + @list.name + "Chat Ticket",  enable_chat_list_path(@list), :class => 'btn', :remote => true %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

here is the chat partial-

```
<div id="chatty" >
  <ol id='messagesDiv' class="conversation">  
  </ol>
  <input id='messageInput' class="conversation" placeholder='Message...'>
  <a href="javascript:$.pageslide.close()"><span class="btn btn-info">Done Chatting</span></a>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".second").pageslide({ direction: "left", modal: true });
  });
</script>
```

Here is the coffeescript file for enabling and writing the chat based on firebase documentation-

```
window.enableChat = (baseRef, projRef, userName, token) ->
  # Get a reference to the root of the chat data.
  messagesRef = new Firebase(baseRef)
  projectRef = ''
  messagesRef.auth token, (error, user) ->
    if error
      $("#messageInput").prop('disabled', true)
      $("#messagesDiv").html('disabled')
    else
      projectRef = messagesRef.child(projRef)

      # Add a callback that is triggered for each chat message.
      projectRef.on "child_added", (snapshot) ->
        message = snapshot.val()
        $("<li class='self'>").append($("<div class='message'>").append($("<p>").text(message.text))).prepend($("<span class='userVal'/>").text(message.name + ": ")).appendTo $("#messagesDiv")

      # When the user presses enter on the message input, write the message to firebase.
      $("#messageInput").keypress (e) ->
        if e.keyCode is 13
          text = $("#messageInput").val()
          projectRef.push 
            name: userName
            text: text
          $("#messageInput").val ""
```

More info 
If I use the chat without activating the pageslide the chat writes to the show page just fine. 
[image]

Once I activate the pageslide and use the text box a new li will be appended to the list on the main show page but will not have any value in it. And nothing with append to the list inside of the pageslide.

[image]

This link `<a href="#chatty" class="second123">Open Chat</a>` is used to open the jQuery pageslide plugin.

Nothing from the console when hitting enter inside the jQuery pageslide plugin.

How can I better troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: I believe I understand the issue better. Pageslide plugin created a `<div id="pageslide"></div>` and I had my chat data wrapped inside of it. I remedied this issue by adding #pageslide before the references in the coffee file. So `$('#messagesDiv')` becomes `$('div#pageslide #messagesDiv')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pageslide plugin created a

`<div id="pageslide"></div>`

and I had my chat data wrapped inside of it. I remedied this issue by adding

`#pageslide`

before the references in the coffee file. So `$('#messagesDiv')`

becomes `$('div#pageslide #messagesDiv')`

Hope this helps someone in the future.